# I'm using Pencil Evolus 1.2 gtk and I can't see the grid

Tags: 10.10, graphics

Screenshot:

[image]

Why is the grid not showing up?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them? That may be your best bet.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards